# Multiple Columns, One String

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Alright, well. I was making a Hashing/Dehashing website for hashing MD5, SHA1, SHA512, etc. While I was making it, I decided to do this table structure:

```
hash_id int(11)
plain_text varchar(100)
hash_md5 varchar(32)    
hash_base64 varchar(500)
hash_sha1 varchar(50)   
hash_sha512 varchar(128)
hash_mysql varchar(50)
```

While making the `Dehash()` function in my class, I figured out that I couldn't just "search" for the string using OR OR OR OR OR without running into performance problems, so I'm asking, is there some sort of MySQL function to help me do this without having performance problems?

Also, with this, another issue might be that I HAVE to get the column name in which the hash lies in, such as:

If I WERE to use OR OR OR OR OR, my query would stand as:

```
$Query = $this->DB->prepare("SELECT plain_text, hash_md5, hash_base64, hash_sha1, hash_sha512, hash_mysql FROM hashes WHERE hash_md5 = ? OR hash_base64 = ? OR hash_sha1 = ? OR hash_sha512 = ? OR hash_mysql = ?");
$Query->bind_param("sssss", $Hash, $Hash, $Hash, $Hash, $Hash);
$Query->execute();
$Query->bind_result($pt,  $md5, $b64, $sha1, $sha512, $mysql);
$Query->fetch();
$Query->close();
```

But don't you see how much of a problem this might cause? As I do this, I would also have to conduct an if statement to check if the columns contain the hash, and if so, that's the column with the hash, but then the other columns take up memory, making my site slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have indexes on all the hash_something fields this should be fast

```
SELECT plain_text, 'md5' as hash_type,
FROM hashes WHERE hash_md5 = ?
UNION 
SELECT plain_text, 'sha1' as hash_type,
FROM hashes WHERE hash_sha1 = ?
UNION 
SELECT plain_text, 'sha512' as hash_type,
FROM hashes WHERE hash_sha512 = ?
UNION 
...
```

If you select it using OR-s mysql will sometimes optimize it to something equivalent but it is not guaranteed

A better way would be to have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE `hashes` (
    `plaintext` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `hash_type` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `hash_value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`plaintext`, `hash_type`),
    INDEX `hash_value` (`hash_value`)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was told that the table structure I'm using would be a faster method due to the fact that it'll take up less rows per encrypted string (if the plain text was the same, that is). Do you think this is true?

Comment: It will take less rows but the amount of data will be the same because you will have more data for every row. Im not really sure which one will be faster. You can make 2 tables, full them up with a few million rows each and try it to be sure.

Comment: Also you can make hash_type an ENUM column to squeeze a few more bytes from it.

Comment: To be sure, I'll conduct a test, as you suggested. My first table structure started out something similar to the one you posted; plain_text, hash_type, hash. I had 12 million rows, and it took rather a few seconds to even get the COUNT of rows (which I used COUNT(plain_text), and fetched that result, which is faster than using a mysql_num_rows, and/or $Query->num_rows). It also took even longer to insert/retrieve a hash from the database, which is why I changed table structures, and I'm in the process of recoding the website.

Comment: Marking as solved for now; I'll reply back if I didn't get what I wanted to accomplish. Thank you.

Comment: COUNT can work fast only if it is COUNT(*) on a MyISAM table. insert/retrieve should work fast if you have an index